# Question to Google regarding API voice to speech voice removal or change

Tags: google-apis-explorer, speech-synthesis

Regarding your voice "Google UK English Female" used on all free (and other) text to speech sites.

Was this voice removed? I heard this could be the case from a professional.

This voice changed to a much lower quality alternative ca. a month ago.

The voice I used was crystal clear, elegant, very personal and well configured (but old yes with flaws) British lady voice. This voice cannot be found on Google voice lists or anywhere on the web anymore.

Help needed, please! This is important for my work.

Regards, Henry

Comment: I do not think Google will read this ?

Answer (score 0):

And sorry for posting here if it's off-topic, it's just so incredibly hard to find answers to this and it's extremely important to me.

Comment: don't post comment as answer.